# How To Disable input Textbox on ASP.Net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please help me solve this problem.
In this project I want to do something when you select a value, I disable text input.
I want this work to be done dynamically.
Language technology project is: ASP.Net MVC 5.
Photo is below:

[image]

Help me please.

Comment: if use jquery $('input').prop("disabled", true);

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Gender, new { @placeholder = "جنسیت", @class = "gender" ,onchange="myFunction()"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NV, new { @placeholder = "انتخاب نظام وظیفه", @class = "NezamVazifeh" })


<script>
function myFunction(){
 var g= $("#Gender").val();
if(g=="fmale")
$("#NV" ).prop( "disabled", true );
}
</script>
```

or use

```
 function myFunction(){
 var g= $("#Gender").val();
if(g=="fmale")
 document.getElementById("NV").disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery in click event to disable the input.

```
$('input').prop("disabled", true);  //use the input element id or class
```